# SAMBA server restore

Tags: samba, domain-controller

Last week I ran into some hardware issues with my SAMBA DC server.
I was able to recover the hard disk, but the other hardware seems to be nonfunctioning.
I have a spare server and would like to restore the SAMBA configuration from the old hard disk. Is this possible, and what directories need to be copied if it is possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: if its the same server, plug abd play to run? usually because Linux usually dont care about hw changes mostly

Comment: It is a new server... with slightly different specs

Comment: Ok then read the Manual, https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Back_up_and_Restoring_a_Samba_AD_DC